# Plotly: one line, different colors

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express, data-presentation

I want to make a 2-dimensional plot with Plotly or Plotly.Express, where a single line of the graph has different colors. That is, I have a list of x-values and a list of y-values leading to points on my graph that should be connected. The connecting line has a color that depends on a third given list. (When you get familiar with my examples, you will notice that the last entry of `color_list` is not used for coloring a line. But this is not a problem and not the subject of this question.)
The lists `x_list`, `y_list`, and `color_list` should be thought of as having many entries (not just six as in my example).

In the beginning, I simply used Plotly.Express for a Scatter plot:

```py
# file mwe1.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y_list = [5,1,1,4,1,3]
color_list = [0,2,0,2,2,1]

px.scatter(x=x_list,
           y=y_list,
           color=color_list).show()
```

This program runs without trouble and draws the following figure:

[image: Output from mwe1.py]

Apart from the very bright and hard to see yellow, this is not bad.
The changes I would like to make are: Connect the points with lines (I will use "horizontal-vertical" mode, but if that is a restriction, the mode is not too important.) Also it would be great if the colors are recognized as a qualitative scale, not a continuous scale.

In the attempt to get connecting lines between the dots, I wrote the following program:

```py
# file mwe2.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y_list = [5,1,1,4,1,3]
color_list = [0,2,0,2,2,1]

px.line(x=x_list,
        y=y_list,
        color=color_list).show()
```

This yielded the following mess:

[image: Output from mwe2.py]

Plotly takes it that I want one figure per color, which is certainly a cool functionality, but not what fits my needs in this situation. (However, the color-legend is now better, as opposed to the continuous scale before.)
Since I was not successful with my search on the internet (the issue pops up frequently on StackOverflow, but it seems there is no simple solution for the desired plots), I tried to build the figure by myself. The following code illustrates this approach:

```py
# file mwe3.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y_list = [5,1,1,4,1,3]
color_list = [0,2,0,2,2,1]

fig = make_subplots()

# now add the segments manually
for i in range(5):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                             x=x_list[i:i+2],
                             y=y_list[i:i+2],
                             line_shape='hv'
                            )
                 )

fig.show()
```

This approach does not yet respect the desired coloring, and so far it works:

[image: Output of mwe3.py]

Too bad that I want the coloring respected. That's why I tried the following:

```py
# file mwe4.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y_list = [5,1,1,4,1,3]
color_list = [0,2,0,2,2,1]

fig = make_subplots()

# now add the segments manually
for i in range(5):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                             x=x_list[i:i+2],
                             y=y_list[i:i+2],
                             line_shape='hv',
                             color=color_list[i]
                            )
                 )

fig.show()
```

This program doesn't run properly. I get a long error message with the essence that there is no valid property called `color`.

What can I do? I have almost given up hope that there is a simple solution in the spirit of `mwe1.py` and `mwe2.py`. So I will appreciate hints how I can control the color of the added trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- have read your question multiple times... I believe this does it
- effectively *color_list* is a discrete color map, so use value to look up a discrete color from `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`
- generate a trace for each pair of co-ordinates

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

x_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y_list = [5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3]
color_list = [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1]


go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=x_list[tn : tn + 2],
            y=y_list[tn : tn + 2],
            line_shape="hv",
            line_color=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[color_list[tn]],
            showlegend=False,
        )
        for tn in range(len(x_list))
    ]
).show()
```

[image: Plot of the constructed figure]

Further hints:

- If you do not want the dots (the so called markers) to appear in your plot, use the parameter `mode="lines"` when calling `go.Scatter(...)`.
- If `color_list` contains more than 10 indices, the list `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly` does not suffice. Have a look at [these options](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Rob! This works great. Is the name `tn` a common abbreviation for somethin? If so, for what? Also (now an actual question) is there an easy way to print a legend? If I set `showlegend=True`, then I get (in my use case) a very long legend. Instead I wish to have a small legend where for each occuring color, the corresponding index `color_list[tn]` is displayed. If there is no such possibility within Plotly, then I can as well manufacture something.

Comment: I added two further hints to reflect my adaption of your answer.

Comment: I used `tn` as an abbreviation for "trace number".  not sure this is any convention... a legend is made up from both the traces and the layout.  so to print out everything in your IDE that makes up a legend `fig.to_dict()` and look at **data** and **layout** contents

Comment: `line_color=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[color_list[tn%len(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)]]` can be used to cycle through colors and avoid index out of range

Comment: In respond to your suggestion `line_color=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[color_list[tn%len(px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)]]`: I would not do that since I want to distinguish between the color 14 and 4 in the plot.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Too bad that this is not implemented in plotly.express!