# Plotly: different colors in one line

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to distinguish weekends from weekdays by either 1) shading the region 2) coloring points with different colors or 3) setting x-axis label marked different for weekend.

Here I am trying the 2nd option — coloring data points for weekend differently. I first created an additional column (Is_Weekday) for distinguish weekends from weekdays. However, it’s not drawn on the same line, but rather draws two lines with different colors. I would like them to be in **one line but with different color for values on weekends**.

[image]

Here’s my code for reproducible data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px

np.random.seed(42)
rng = pd.date_range('2022-04-10', periods=21, freq='D')
practice_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 
practice_df = practice_df.set_index('Date')

weekend_list = []
for i in range(len(practice_df)):
    if practice_df.index[i].weekday() > 4:
        weekend_list.append(True)
    else:
        weekend_list.append(False)

practice_df['IsWeekend'] = weekend_list

fig = px.line(temp_df, 
              x=temp_df.index, y='cnt', 
              color = 'Is_Weekend',
              markers=True)
fig.show()
```

What I want to do would look something like this but coloring data points/line for weekends differently.

[image: image2]

---

**Edit:**

Thanks so much to @Derek_O, I was able to color weekend with my original dataset. But I'd want to color the friday-saturday line also colored as weekend legend, so I set `practice_df.index[i].weekday() >= 4` instead of `practice_df.index[i].weekday() > 4`.

1. But would it be possible to have the Friday point to be the same as weekdays.
2. Also, is it possible to have a straight line connecting the points, not like stairs?
3. Otherwise, it'd also work if we could shade weekend region like the image at the bottom.

[image: image3]
[image: image4]

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @Rob Raymond's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69741932/5327068), we can loop through the `practice_df` two elements at a time, adding a trace to the `fig` for each iteration of the loop.

We also only want to show the legend category the first time it occurs (so that the legend entries only show each category like `True` or `False` once), which is why I've created a new column called `"showlegend"` that determines whether the legend is shown or not.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)
rng = pd.date_range('2022-04-10', periods=21, freq='D')
practice_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 
practice_df = practice_df.set_index('Date')

weekend_list = []
for i in range(len(practice_df)):
    if practice_df.index[i].weekday() > 4:
        weekend_list.append(True)
    else:
        weekend_list.append(False)

practice_df['IsWeekend'] = weekend_list

weekend_color_map = {True:0, False:1}
weekend_name_map = {True:"True", False:"False"}
practice_df['color'] = practice_df['IsWeekend'].map(weekend_color_map)
practice_df['name'] = practice_df['IsWeekend'].map(weekend_name_map)

## use the color column since weekend corresponds to 0, nonweekend corresponds to 1
first_weekend_idx = practice_df['color'].loc[practice_df['color'].idxmin()]
first_nonweekend_idx = practice_df['color'].loc[practice_df['color'].idxmax()]
practice_df["showlegend"] = False
showlegendIdx = practice_df.columns.get_indexer(["showlegend"])[0]
practice_df.iat[first_weekend_idx, showlegendIdx] = True
practice_df.iat[first_nonweekend_idx, showlegendIdx] = True
practice_df["showlegend"] = practice_df["showlegend"].astype(object)

fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=practice_df.index[tn : tn + 2],
            y=practice_df['Val'][tn : tn + 2],
            mode='lines+markers',
            # line_shape="hv",
            line_color=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[practice_df['color'][tn]],
            name=practice_df['name'][tn],
            legendgroup=practice_df['name'][tn],
            showlegend=practice_df['showlegend'][tn],
        )
        for tn in range(len(practice_df))
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Is Weekend')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I changed the weekend to start from Friday to have the Friday-Saturday line colored as weekend by setting `practice_df.index[i].weekday() >= 4`, but it colors Friday point as weekend as well. So I wonder if it's possible to 1) have Friday point still colored different from weekend points and 2) connect dots with a straight line instead of a stair-like line. Please refer to my edits in the question section above. Again, thanks so much for your contribution :)

Comment: @user9532692 you can fix the dots being connected with a straight line by getting rid of the argument `line_shape="hv"`. i am not sure about making Fridays differently colored from the weekends, but it should be possible, probably by passing an array of colors to `go.Scatter` – i'll circle back to this when i have the chance later